# Caching and session variables (PHP, MySQL...)

Tags: php, mysql, session, caching

Apologies in advance for the lengthy post, just trying to explain the situation clearly.

I've created a PHP-driven website for searching a big (millions of records) MySQL database of people. On the search page you have your usual form for search criteria. Due to the way the people often use the site, the search criteria are saved into session variables so that if the search page is reloaded the previous criteria remain in the form fields (there's a button to manually reset the criteria, of course). This in itself works fine.

I also have two language selection links that store the language selection in a session variable (making the page header load an appropriate localization file), and as above, this in itself also works fine.

What's problematic is that when a user gets the search result, a list of people, and wants to open up detailed info on a person (thus going from search.php to info.php) and then wants to go back to the people listing via the back button, it takes too long to reload the previous page as the page re-sends the MySQL query etc, instead of going back to a cached page. It can take even 5 seconds or more sometimes as the queries produce up to 5000 results - but even say, 200-500 results takes long to reload because the database itself is big and not the fastest in the world. And limiting the number of results isn't really practical.

The obvious solution at first glance would SEEM to be enabling the browser cache. Which is exactly what I did via PHP header and pragma controls. And all seemed well, as going back to the list was basically instantaneous. However, I realized that enabling the cache means the updated session variables don't work. New search criteria doesn't properly replace the old ones when reloading the search page after having been to a different page, and even though you select another language, pages open up in the language you previously were using, because that's the way they were cached! You can force the language to update via F5, but that doesn't seem to help the search criteria much. But even if it did, F5-spam isn't really an answer, it needs to work automatically.

So long story short, how do I make the search result list open quickly without making session variables useless? Or will I simply have to make do with sluggish page loads when using back button, thus annoying users? I really don't want to open the info.php in a new page, either.

Comment: are you using in both call of search.php the same URL  and Queries?

Comment: is the session key the same between calling search.php and info.php?

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you considered a lightbox? As long as the user info that they are viewing isn't too long, that could give your page a cleaner refresh-free quality by not forcing your viewer to leave the page. You can pull the data from the user via AJAX. Just a thought.

Comment: Have you done something that defeats the MySQL query cache?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: search.php uses GET, so the variables are in the URL, and thus when one goes back from info.php the url is the same as last time, no prompt to resend the form or anything.

Comment: The session is the same between both files, both include the same header.php that uses a named session. I also haven't done anything to prevent the query cache from working, but it seems not to anyway. Or well, I'm using PDO for the first time in this project, so I don't know how it works with that. Originally I assumed some sort of cache would handle it by default, but no such luck apparently.

Comment: A LightBox is a possibility I suppose and I did consider it, though I've never used it except with images, so I'd have to see how it works with text and stuff. Problem is I've never managed to get, well, ANYTHING working in terms of AJAX, for some reason. I guess I've given up too easy, but I always seem to end up stumped when I try anything with it, no matter how simple supposedly.

Comment: On second thought I'm not sure if LightBox would work, at least easily, because the info.php contains links to itself with new variables passed in the URL - for example, a link from a parent's info to his/her child's info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered caching the database results on the file system? I have found the Zend Framework caching class to be very easy to use. You can use any information you want, to differentiate cached results from other cached results. So the caching can be as fine grained as required.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html

You don't need to use the whole of Zend Framework to use the class. You can use it on its own.